# Displaying multiple columns on one row (SQL)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a report I am trying to make that displays parent information and all children in one household on ONE row. 
There is no "parent" table that stores the information on parents and there is no ID that links parents to child and no ID that links sibling to sibling. The only way to tell if they are siblings is if they have the same address (logic being that if they have the same address, they live together, and are part of the same household). All the information is pulled from a "student" table or a custom field in the student table that stores the parent information, address they live at, etc.

Instead of displaying parent info twice I want to display 
the information like this:
Parent_name, address, phone,child1_name, child1_schoolname, child1_age, child2_name, child2_schoolname, child2_age, etc(for every child in that household)

The problem is that not every household will have the same amount of children and I can only link siblings by their address.

How can I display all information for each household on ONE row? Is this possible and how? I've tried pivot table but with no avail.

Comment: You should modify your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I think what you want is a pivot table

Comment: I've tried pivot table but I don't want to aggregate the data and there is no connecting field . I just may not know the power of a pivot table but a pivot table hasn't helped in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic 'you shouldn't be doing reports in the database' question. A database is for data retrieval, not data formatting. But let's assume you know this and need to do it anyway for some reason.

The algorithm I'd use for this would be

1. Create some windowed queries across the data; group by address (the joinable value) and `sort by age desc`.
2. Create a query that utilize this window and returns the first item in each group.
3. Create additional queries that return the second, the third, the fourth, in each group. etc.
4. Outer join these together.

This is going to be far easier if you define some maximum number of siblings (five?) as opposed to dynamically building these siblings.

If the parents are in the same table, how do you know which items are parents and which are children?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have two tables one for Parent(first table) and one for Children(second table) as below:

[image]

[image]

You can do something like that in your data model:

```
select Parent.NAME as parent_name,
   Parent.ADDRESS as parent_address,
   Parent.PHONE AS phone,
   (
        select listagg(Child.NAME,',')
              within group(order by Child.NAME)
        from CHILD Child
        where Child.ADDRESS=Parent.ADDRESS
   )as children_names,       
   (
        select 
              listagg(Child.AGE,',')
              within group(order by Child.NAME)
        from CHILD Child
        where Child.ADDRESS=Parent.ADDRESS
   )as children_ages
from PARENT Parent .
```

And you will have the output query result:

[image]

**Listagg** is your solution which operates as you want bringing muliple rows in one.

However,listagg is compatible for database 11g and newest versions,
so in case you have older version,this is not going to work.

Hope this help.

Comment: Useful for two tables but I only have one.